# How to make JFrame login form work?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, authentication

I am doing a project on library management in java using swing on eclipse. When I click on the login button nothing happens. The mysql jdbc driver is loaded and I am getting the connection but no label appears. Please tell me what to do. Here is my code.

```
    import java.awt.*;  
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.sql.*;
    public class Loginscreen implements ActionListener {

    JFrame logframe;
    JButton bt;
    JLabel lid, lpass, lmsg;
    JTextField tid;
    JPasswordField pass;
    JPanel p1;
    Font ft, ft2;
    Connection conn;

    public Loginscreen() {

        logframe = new JFrame("Login");
        logframe.setSize(1366, 720);
        logframe.setVisible(true);
        lid = new JLabel("User ID");
        lpass = new JLabel("Password");
        lmsg = new JLabel();
        ft = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 30);
        ft2 = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20);
        tid = new JTextField();
        pass = new JPasswordField();
        p1 = new JPanel();
        bt = new JButton("Login");
        logframe.add(p1);
        p1.setLayout(null);
        p1.setBackground(new Color(160, 82, 45));//Background Color Set
        lid.setBounds(450, 200, 500, 30);
        p1.add(lid);
        lid.setFont(ft);
        tid.setBounds(650, 200, 200, 30);
        p1.add(tid);
        tid.setFont(ft2);
        lpass.setBounds(450, 300, 500, 30);
        p1.add(lpass);
        lpass.setFont(ft);
        pass.setBounds(650, 300, 200, 30);
        p1.add(pass);
        bt.setBounds(600, 430, 100, 50);
        p1.add(bt);
        bt.setFont(new Font("Segoe Script", Font.BOLD, 22));
        bt.setBackground(new Color(173, 216, 230));
        lmsg.setBounds(450, 510, 500, 30);
        p1.add(lmsg);
        bt.addActionListener(this);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if (ae.getSource() == bt) {
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_lib", "root", "admin");
                String i = tid.getText();//get the user id
                char[] pwd = pass.getPassword();//get the password
                String spwd = new String(pwd);//converting char to string
                String query = "select * from tbl_user where id=? and password=?";
                PreparedStatement p = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                p.setString(1, i);
                p.setString(2, spwd);
                ResultSet rs = p.executeQuery();
                int count = 0;
                while (rs.next()) {
                    count = count + 1;
                }
                if (count == 1) {
                    lmsg.setText("Invalid User ID or Password");
                } else {
                    lmsg.setText("Invalid User ID or Password");
                }
                rs.close();
                conn.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note, you shouldn't make the frame visible until you have added all the components .

Comment: can you print your `spwd` and `i` please?

Comment: your program work fine with me

Answer (score 0):

I guess you dont set the text when it succeeds.

Also make sure

```
while(rs.next())
{
count=count+1;
}
```

terminates.
Also secure your query against SQL-Injection (just realized this)

For these kinds of debugging problems I recommend UnitTesting (basically just test how far the program goes, how long it takes, if it terminates etc).

Also before you post a question, do us a favor to add comments and format the GUI-stuff properly...it looks horrible :/

EDIT:

```
  if(count==1)
        {
            lmsg.setText("Invalid User ID or Password");
        }
        else
        {
            lmsg.setText("Invalid User ID or Password");
        }
```

Does not make sense to me... Whatever happens you return an error